# Not able to run IIS based tests in VS Online Hosted CI

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, iis, continuous-integration, azure-devops

Here is my situation. I have a ASP.Net web forms application with code hosted in Visual Studio Online using TFVC. I recently started using CI tools in VS Online to automate everything from building, unit testing, integration testing and production deployment.
I started in baby steps. The build is working, it runs unit tests. But when it comes to unit testing using IIS, it throws below error inside the CI console.

> [error]   The test or test run is configured to run in ASP.NET in IIS,
>   but the current user (TASKAGENT-0005\buildguest) is not in the
>   Administrators group. Running tests in ASP.NET in IIS requires the
>   user to be in the Administrators group.

I could see that its clearly telling about admin privileges. Googling is not giving any suggestions. Any idea how to give permission? Also is VSOnline supports testing by hosting ASP.Net  temporarily in build machine. Below is the unit test method which I use to test by hosting inside IIS.

```
[TestMethod]
[HostType("ASP.NET")]
[UrlToTest(Common.BaseUrl + "Blogs.aspx")]
public void WhenChangeLogPageIsRequested_TitleShouldBeProper()
{//Code goes here
}
```

Comment: Did you try adding the specified username to the administrators group on the server? I did a quick web search for "windows server add administrator" and got a lot of hits.

Comment: Thanks..This CI runs inside Azure hosted VS Online machines. Needs to check how can I add admin to those Azure machines? Or do VS Online allows adding admins to their machines in cloud.

Comment: But I think still they dont provide a free machine for running integration tests. Now I am using AppVeyor CI and works fine for me:)

Answer (score 0):

A typical continuous integration and Continuous Delivery workflow will contain:

> 1.Create a new Agent Pool, install Build Agent and configure permissions
>
> 2.Create a new build definition and configure it to execute Unit Tests (Continuous Integration)
>
> 3.Package our the built website as a Web Deploy Package
>
> 4.Create a Machine Group and add a new test web server
>
> 5.Use PowerShell DSC to configure a basic web server (IIS, ASP.NET 4.5, Website & WebDeploy)
>
> 6.Use WebDeploy to deploy the site package to the newly configured Web Server
>
> 7.Auto deploy and configure the new Test Agent on our web server
>
> 8.Run Coded UI Tests and report results

Follow the video at website: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/07/17/video-configuring-continuous-integration-and-continuous-testing-with-visual-studio-2015.aspx

Comment: Thanks let me see the video. Its seems many scripts to be written to orchestrate apart from the test cases:)

Comment: It seems I needs to have a separate machine to host my web site in IIS(step 4) before running the integration tests. There is no way to host my site in the VS Online build machine as It don't have IIS in it.Even I tried to host my site using ASP.Net APIs. But it seems without admin privilege in VS Online build machine, its not working. The project is my personal one and no budget to host a machine for testing. So finally moved to deadly Github + AppVeyor combination where I can host my site in Appveyor build machine and run tests.I used FakeHost from nuget for hosting site when the test starts